# Fetch .json file present in public folder doesn't work after build in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch, create-react-app, eel

I am trying to fetch data from a json file called `tmp.json` that is present in the root of public folder. My app was created using CRA. Here's the code that I wrote for it:-

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "../components/button";
import { Container, Row, Carousel, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Header from "../components/Header.js";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.js";
import Card from "../components/card";
import axios from "axios";

const Commit = () => {
  let [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

  axios.get("tmp.json").then((res) => {
    setFileList((fileList = res.data));
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={"12"}>
            <Carousel indicators={false}>
              {fileList.map((file, idx) => {
                return (
                  <Carousel.Item key={idx}>
                    <Card
                      key={idx}
                      heading={file.path.split("\\").pop()}
                      content={file.changes}
                    />
                  </Carousel.Item>
                );
              })}
            </Carousel>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Commit;
```

This works absolutely fine before build but after build this doesn't work. It simply cannot resolve the promise. Although the json file is present in the build folder but I simply cannot fetch it. Any help would save me a ton of time

Comment: You can't send request inside component function, every render will call your axios get method, instead of this wrap this function with useEffect hook, second thing when you are importing file don't use axios, simply write import() and then you will get promise to catch data. Where have you placed your tmp.json file? Inside public folder?

Comment: @Freestyle09 yes , the json file is present in public folder and as i said I created the app using CRA which I suppose does't allow outside src imports.